# How can I post contents in code format?

Tags: support

I'm trying to post somethings in LibGdx code format in this site (I'm new here), but I can't do it...

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Ctrl-K will indent code and create a code block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...

Comment: But I didn't understand how it work...

Comment: What do I do if I'm not using a desktop???

Comment: Please read the [help], it goes over the options. If you don’t have a traditional keyboard or your mobile layout doesn’t show he appropriate UI you can always just type the Markdown in directly.

Answer (score 2):

Surround the text you want with `backticks` and will appear as inline code.

```
Put four spaces in front of each line of text
    you want to appear
        as a block of code.
```

You can [click the "edit" link under this post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2599/edit) to see exactly what the post content looks like.

There are also buttons you can press above the text edit area, some of which have key mappings. Control-K will create code blocks for selected text, for example; pressing the `{}` button above the text box does the same thing.

[This section of the Help Center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) explains the formatting features in more detail.